# List all jobs in all shell sessions (not just the current shell), by current user

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, job-control, jobs

I know that the `jobs` command only shows jobs running in current shell session.

Is there a bash code that will show jobs across shell sessions (for example, jobs from another terminal tab) for current user?

Comment: `ps x` shows all the processes of the given user.

Comment: @choroba cool. how to use `ps x` to list only running jobs?

Comment: That seems to be impossible, because it seems need explore another bash process's internal data

Comment: Maybe filter out processes whose session leader is a bash process can work

Comment: What is the point of showing the jobs from a shell session if you cannot interact with it in another one?

You can _disown_ it from the original shell, but it will still be attach from the tty it was launched.

What is your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear (to me) what you'd want this global `jobs` call to do beyond just listing all processes owned by the current user (`ps x`), but you could filter that listing by terminal and/or by state.

List your processes that are:

- Connected to any terminal: `ps x |awk '$2 ~ /pts/'`
- Stopped by job control (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> without `bg`): `ps x |awk '$3 ~ /T/'`
- Running in the foreground: `ps x |awk '$3 ~ /\+/'`

[AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is really powerful. Here we're just calling out fields by number and looking at their values (`$`) with regular expression matchers (`~`). You can invert a match with `!~`. These are conditions and we're simply using AWK's default action (print matches, which could also be written like `{ print $0 }` to print the whole line).

You can add the title with `'NR == 1 || …` (number of records = 1, aka line 1) in the AWK command. These can be combined, e.g. `ps x |awk 'NR == 1 || $3 ~ /T/ || $2 ~ /pts/`. Using regular expressions, you can combine the first two bullets as `ps x |awk '$3 ~ /[T+]/'`. These conditional statements are logical, so you can combine `||` with `&&` and parentheses, e.g. `ps x |awk 'NR == 1 || ($3 ~ /\+/ && $2 ~ /pts/)'`

I suspect what you want is: `ps x |awk 'NR == 1 || $2 ~ /pts/`

I ran this on a Linux system. If you're running something else, your terminal emulators may be named differently. Run `ps $$` to take a look at how your active shell appears on the list and build a regular expression from the second column.